# AppCompatButton getting flat after change the background color

Tags: android

I just updated my android Studio and every time that I try to change the background color of `AppCompatButton` the layout gets flat and looses the ripple effect, it wasn't like that.

[image]

And normal :

[image]

In my old project, works fine too!

[image]

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="Login"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Logar"
        android:focusable="true" />
```

Comment: Which `Theme` do you use? try using `Theme.AppCompat` or `Theme.MaterialComponents`

Answer (score 0):

A good way to change your buttons background and keep the ripple effect is to create a separate drawable for them.
So you would create a **default_button_background.xml** with some pre-defined colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/button_ripple_color">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_corner_radius" />
            <solid android:color="@color/buttonBackground" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Then you can assign this drawable to your button background like:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/default_button_background"/>
```